# Android studio horizontal layout troubles

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, layout

So, I'm trying to get something like this.

[image]

And I am having a problem lining up the **+** and **-** buttons in the same line.

Once I have the horizontal layout, and I drag the buttons. I end up with this. I don't know how to make it work, from code or design window. Please help.

[image]

Any solution?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/suma"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="171dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="incrementaContador"
            android:text="+" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/resta"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="169dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="restaContador"
            android:text="-" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/titulo"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:text="Cafe del dia "
            android:textAlignment="center" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/contadorA"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/reinicio"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="Reinicio"
        android:onClick="reseteaContador" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like this. Paste this code in your code window.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/titulo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:text="Cafe del dia " />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/contadorA"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/titulo"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="4"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/button_layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/contadorA"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/suma"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:onClick="incrementaContador"
            android:text="+"
            android:textSize="30sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/resta"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:onClick="restaContador"
            android:text="-"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/reinicio"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
        android:onClick="reseteaContador"
        android:text="Reinicio" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

From my point of view, it is easier to get appropriate design by coding it. I am having something like this.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You've got

`android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_marginTop="171dp"`

on one button and

`android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_marginBottom="169dp"`

on the other.

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/suma"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="incrementaContador"
            android:text="+" />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/resta"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="restaContador"
            android:text="-" />


    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/titulo"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:text="Cafe del dia "
            android:textAlignment="center" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/contadorA"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/reinicio"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="Reinicio"
        android:onClick="reseteaContador"
        />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have too many nested views. You could just use a vertical Linear Layout as parent viewgroup and a horizontal linear layout **with layout weight 1** for the middle two buttons.

For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/titulo"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:text="Cafe del dia "
    android:textAlignment="center" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/contadorA"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:text="24"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/suma"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
        android:onClick="incrementaContador"
        android:text="+" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/resta"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="restaContador"
        android:text="-" />

</LinearLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/reinicio"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="Reinicio"
    android:onClick="reseteaContador" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**Best if you use constraintLayout once you learn to use it.**

Answer (score 0):

You should instead use a ConstraintLayout to achieve what you want. It will be more efficient than using a RelativeLayout, especially nesting sub-layouts inside it. With the ConstraintLayout, you can use the GUI builder to drag the elements around the screen and get them pixel-perfect. The ConstraintLayout may require a bit of work but it is really powerful and you can get major performance gains when you have complex Viewgroup hierarchies consisting of many nested ViewGroups.

But as a solution to your problem here is the updated code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
                tools:context=".MainActivity"
                tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/suma"
            android:layout_width="75dp"
            android:layout_height="75dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:onClick="incrementaContador"
            android:textSize="35sp"
            android:text="+" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/resta"
            android:layout_width="75dp"
            android:layout_height="75dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:onClick="restaContador"
            android:textSize="35sp"
            android:text="-" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/titulo"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:text="Contender"
            android:textAlignment="center" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/contadorA"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="35sp"
            android:text="4"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/reinicio"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:onClick="reseteaContador"
        android:text="Reinicio"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

See on the picture the property that will put text box below the button. 
Then you get the squigly line in red circle indicating the relation.
How to space it even further down the page, I'm still working on. (you could use padding, but I'm sure there is better solution)
[click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XMyoD.jpg)

Comment: Oh, it's in the section: Constraints